# React native app blink and did not open after successful 'react-native run-android'

Tags: android, react-native

After successful build app it open and white screen appears for 2 sec and hide every time I click on the icon this happens.

## react-native run-android

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 57s
118 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 116 up-to-date
<-------------> 0% WAITING
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
info Running C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 8BG7S16202003644 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
info Starting the app on 8BG7S16202003644 (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 8BG7S16202003644 shell am start -n com.teechow/com.teechow.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.teechow/.MainActivity }
```

## react-native start

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\CHECKING\teechow\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\androidx\arch'
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at NodeWatcher.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\CHECKING\teechow\node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js:291:16)
    at callback (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\CHECKING\teechow\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
```

Comment: Try to run the command after opening `cmd as admin`. Also, try `cd android` and run `gradlew clean`

Comment: i already used that command but still same issue.This issue occurs when i was working on some other issues like change the app icon and and also change the name of the app on changing the name of the app i got some errors from firebase about the not matching of application id i fix.I fix it deleting the old app in firebase and install new app for android and the also replace the google services json file.

Comment: Just try restarting your PC and first run `gradlew clean` in `andoid` directory, and then outside `react-native run-android`

Comment: ok let me try restarting my pc because sometimes restarting pc works.

Comment: Yes, also clearing files in `%temp%` folder might help. It's not any major issue, it sometimes misbehaves!

Comment: still same issue